# Is there any statistic or key score that computes the level of reputation vs the time you're a member?

Tags: feature-request, statistics, top-users

I have been a member for one year and 4 months and I accumulated more than 6400 in reputation. I think it is not bad, given that I can't be visiting the site as much as I'd like. I've been checking the scores and information about top users, even by tag; however, I can't find any statistic that measures the level of reputation vs how much time the user has been member. A kind of key value for this relationship

**Dummy Example**

```
User1 --> Reputation 10k --> Member for 5 years 
User2 --> Reputation 5k  --> Member for 1 year
```

If I apply a simple mathematical rule (for example, reputation per day vs account longevity)

```
10k/5 -> 2k per year / 5,55 per day
5k/1 --> 5k per year / 13,88 per day
```

The aforementioned statistic tells me that `user2` has a better scoring per time in the site than `user1`.

Is there something like this?

Comment: I guess you can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) or make a user script to get this metric, if you want. I think perhaps you're putting a lot of importance on reputation points. Why not reviews or helpful flags or vote counts? Total chat messages? :) Or something unmeasurable, like helpfulness? :)

Comment: I concur in that I wouldn't think of acquiring a lot of rep in short time as a sign of anything other than that you acquired a lot of rep in short time. It is just an indicator of how fast one can accumulate wealth - neither good nor bad by itself. It might make a nice userscript, though :)

Comment: A proxy for this could be the yearly reputation league, there you are currently on [page 136](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=136&tab=reputation&filter=year).

Comment: What is the feature-request for? To get this published somewhere? Personally I think this statistic would be damaging to this site. Might as well make a badge for "quickest answer" and "most duplicates answered"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the following SEDE query, as I've done [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1482631/reputation-per-day-leaderboard):

```sql
DECLARE @DumpDate DateTime
-- From rene's answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361312/165261
SET @DumpDate = (select create_date from sys.tables where object_id = object_id('Users'))

SELECT TOP 1000
  Id as [User Link],
  DATEDIFF(day, CreationDate, @DumpDate) as [Days on Site],
  Reputation,
  CAST(Reputation as decimal)/DATEDIFF(day, CreationDate, @DumpDate) as [Rep per Day]
FROM Users
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(day, CreationDate, @DumpDate) >= 7 -- Gotta be here at least a week
ORDER BY [Rep per Day] DESC
```

The unsurprising winners are also the [top two users of all time](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) and [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (but maybe not in the order you'd expect), with an impressive 329.1 and 270.6 reputation per day, respectively, over the 3553 and 4755 days they've each been on the site.

Comment: So given the current averages, Gordon will overtake Jon in 2011 days ;-)